Images from file system are loaded very slowly when on VPS, faster on localhost
My / endpoint returns eleven DTOs, each DTO having a String field imagePath, which looks something like this http://localhost:8082/api/get_image/imagename.png (when on VPS, the imagePath looks like this: http://123.456.78.901/api/get_image/imagename.png).
Another endpoint /get_image returns an image with the provided name:
@GetMapping(value = "get_image/{name}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage(@PathVariable(name = "name") String name)  {
  ...
  byte[] image = this.fileService.getFile(fullPath);
  return image;
}

I use this method in my Spring code to load images from file system:
    public byte[] getFile(String path)  {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        } catch (IOException e)  {
            return null;
        }
    }

When I load the page with images, on localhost (my home PC, the folder with images is also located on the same PC), I get this result:

But when I deploy the same code on VPS (the folder with images is copied to the VPS computer as well), I get this:

The difference in speed is startling - 356 ms vs 11.13 s.
I hosted all eleven images on imgur website and made it so that the controller returns the DTOs with imgur links, rather than links that point to the controller's get_image endpoint.
Then the performance looks like this:


For some reason, there is still a difference, but a much smaller one and the VPS performance is much better.
Also after several refreshes, the localhost starts loading much faster, I assume due to browser cashing:

Which isn't the case with VPS.
I'm not sure what's going on here. Each image has size ranging from 1MB to 2MB. The dimensions of each image are 1456x816. I could potentially make each image smaller, but it appears wrong to me that loading mere 13MB of data would take that long, especially considering it's much faster on localhost.

Sounds like cache. Otherwise not much to say without knowledge of the infrastructure. Which is probably some type of pseudo converged storage.

@GregAskew What do you mean by infrastructure? It's just an Ubuntu server, with a ~/images folder that is read by the getFile method. The stack is Java's Spring framework, which I think uses Tomcat webserver. Do you mean to say that on localhost the webserver cashes the images and returns them faster, compared to the webserver on the VPS?
